# how can i recover windows chk-files extensions in linux bash

Tags: windows, linux, bash, file-recovery

After a scan disk i have a lot of CHK-files in folders like "found.000", ...

I can find out the extensions with the file command:

```
for i in /media/Daten/found.*/*.chk ; do file $i; done
```

how can I use this to reconstruct all file extensions to these files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This technique WILL NOT WORK FOR ALL FILES.  I used to use this to help with data recovery.

```
for i in /media/Daten/found.*/*.chk; do mv "$i" "$i".$(grep $(file -bi $i | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/;//') /etc/mime.types | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'); done
```

The way this works is it uses the mime type functionality in the `file` command then greps /etc/mime.types for it, picks the first extension in the list and then renames the file to that.

This command will do mass renames, it will move first and ask questions later, so be 100% sure you're running this on the correct directory.

Next time, do not use chkdsk to recover files.  You can damage them beyond repair.  chkdsk will OM NOM NOM your data and burp afterwards.  Always use recovery software to get back the files you need before you chkdsk.

Generally, the files are named .CHK though, not .chk (just fyi.)

Comment: thx, that worked. but can you somehow not rename files, if there is no extension found? and exclude directories too?

Comment: I've given you all of the tools to fix this job.  What you're asking about is trivial to implement.  Research the `bash` if statement.  Together, with my solution laid out on a platter, and your research into how to tweak it, we can work together and build you the exact solution you want.

Comment: ok, maybe i'll find out how to change exe extensions then to ".exe" instead of ".bin". but for a start this already works fine to me. thx ;)

Comment: This worked for me, however it retained the .CHK in the filenames with the added extension. To fix this I changed the following part of the command: do mv "$i" "${i%.CHK}"

Answer (score 4):

To recover specific file types, first see what's there. Tested on OS X:

```
file --mime -b /media/Daten/FOUND.*/*.CHK | sort | uniq

application/octet-stream; charset=binary
application/ogg; charset=binary
application/pdf; charset=binary
application/zip; charset=binary
audio/x-wav; charset=binary
image/jpeg; charset=binary
image/png; charset=binary
video/3gpp; charset=binary
```

Then, for the types you want to keep:

```
mkdir /tmp/renamed

for f in /media/Daten/FOUND.*/*.CHK
do file --mime $f \
  | perl -n -e \
  '/^([^.]*).*(3gpp|jpeg|ogg|png|wav)/ && print "$1.CHK /tmp/renamed/$1.$2\n"' \
  | xargs cp
done
```

This uses `file --mime` (or `file -I`, or `file -i` on Linux) to determine the MIME type, then passes the line with both the filename and the MIME type to Perl, which uses a regular expression to capture the base name (like `FILE0001`) and the file type (like `jpeg`) and prints a line like `FILE0001.CHK /tmp/renamed/FILE0001.jpeg`. Finally, that line is passed to `cp`.

(The `\` continues a single-line command on the next line.)

Comment: cool thx, but should be a small i letter:   file -ib /media/Daten/found.00*/*.* | sort | uniq; this part works, but the rest i cannot run on ubuntu

Comment: Ah, not on OS X: *-i If the file is a regular file, do not classify its contents* versus *-I, --mime Causes the file command to output mime type strings*. Funny people. I'll change to `--mime` then!

Comment: Any error message for the other parts? Maybe making it one line (with some semi-colons) helps?